# How to run a macro when click merge cell VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I want to click a cell and run a macro to make border if the cell doesn't have it, and if the cell has the border it will erase the border. but I can't do it when cell is merged.

This code is only working for normal cell, can't run if I merge L11 and L12 :

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("L11")) Is Nothing Then

        If ActiveSheet.Range("L11").Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle <> xlLineStyleNone And ActiveSheet.Range("L11").Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle <> xlLineStyleNone Then

            'if has border erase it.
            ActiveSheet.Range("L11").Borders.LineStyle = xlNone


        Else

            'if doesn't have border create it.
            ActiveSheet.Range("L11").Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous

        End If
```

I try to use same code and change the range but it doesn't work for detect when clicking and for create a border for merge cell.

```
If Intersect(Target, Range("$M$11:$N$11")) Is Nothing Then
```

can someone please give me solution for this problem.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got something working using the Worksheet_SelectionChange event:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle <> xlLineStyleNone And 
Target.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle <> xlLineStyleNone Then
    'if has border erase it.
    Target.Borders.LineStyle = xlNone
Else
    'if doesn't have border create it.
    Target.Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
End If
End Sub
```

When you click on a merged cell, it thinks the range is the top-left cell.  In my code, the merged cell is just passed as the "Target", which gives you the reference you need.

If you want to limit this to only some cells, you can filter it by addresses.  The

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
'//Filter to limit behavior to cell we want:
If InStr(1, Target.AddressLocal, "$L$11") Then      '//for a merged cell, .AddressLocal looks something like $L$11:$L$12
    If Target.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle <> xlLineStyleNone And 
    Target.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle <> xlLineStyleNone Then
        'if has border erase it.
        Target.Borders.LineStyle = xlNone
    Else
        'if doesn't have border create it.
        Target.Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Because a merged cell has a .AddressLocal in the form of $TopLeftCell:$BottomRightCell, you can filter on the address of the top-left cell to determine which ones get this treatment.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.its work to create border on merge cell but, how to create condition for this code only work on certain cell like L11 and L12(I merge L11 and L12).

Answer (score 0):

Using the most of your code, a simple one-line does the trick for me:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Not Intersect(Target, Range("L11")) Is Nothing Then Range("L11").MergeArea.Borders.LineStyle = (Range("L11").MergeArea.Borders.LineStyle = 1) + 1
End Sub
```

You just missed `Range.MergeArea` ;)